# How do you simulate a mouse click event on a minimized window

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I'm creating an autoclicker with the feature mentioned in the title, I've found a couple of sources that contain something like this, but it still doesn't really work. The best one was the top answer on this question: [programmatically mouse click in another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355286/programmatically-mouse-click-in-another-window) Sadly it doesn't work when its minimized or on another desktop. Really hope someone can help since I've been looking for 3 hours on trying to find anything that helps.

Comment: you find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923061/creating-a-ghost-mouse-to-simulate-mouse-clicks  ???

Comment: I'm trying a similar one... but I don't have the problem of using individual windows... since everything happens in the same software in the same window, what I'm trying to do is get the coordinates and click on the main form; from a child form where I set the XD event...